# Regex for value less than X

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a website which uses google analytics to collect event values (annual salaries). I want to see the average event value, but it is often skewed by people entering exceptionally large values.

I want a regex which will filter out values above 5 million (5000000).

Or, if it’s easier, I would also be happy for a regex which only accepts values of 7 characters, so any value up to 9999999.

I have no idea how to write a regex for google analytics and couldn’t find any similar examples.

Cheers.

Comment: I suggest creating a capture group and then checking the value by code.

Comment: @AvinashRaj my attempts were so way off the mark they aren't worth posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not used to google analytics, but if you want to limit a match to a certain amount of characters, use the right [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), e.g.

```
\b\d{1,7}\b
```

to match numbers with 1 to 7 digits.

`\b` is matching a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), means there is not a word character before or following.

`\d` is matching a digit

`{1,7}` is a quantifier matching 1 to 7 repetitions

Regexes are matching patterns, means they don't know anything about the semantic of the matched characters. So, matching a certain value of a number is not easy with regex and should be avoided.

Comment: This is great and works well. I understand that regex is more complex for specific numbers, that is probably why all examples I have looked at have had me confused. This is easy to adapt to 6 digits too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use a [number range RegEx generator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)